# Rings that inject in all p-adic integers

Tags: p-adic-numbers

Denote $p$ a prime number and $\mathbb Z _p$ the ring of $p$-adic integers.
We have a canonical injective ring homomorphism $:\mathbb Z \rightarrow \mathbb Z_p$ for all $p$. But $\mathbb Z$ is not the largest ring that maps into all $\mathbb Z_p$. 
Consider for instance the ring of all formal series 
$$
F := \left\{ \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n \cdot n! \; ,\; 0\leq a_n\leq n \right\}.
$$
Since $(n!)_n$ converges $p$-adically to zero for every $p$, this gives a canonical morphism $\phi_p: F\rightarrow \mathbb Z_p$.

I must admit that $\phi_p$ is not injective, but the intersection 
$\bigcap\limits_p \ker \phi_p$ is zero. 
So, what is known about rings $R$ containing $\mathbb{Z}$ and having "canonical" morphisms $\phi_p:R\rightarrow \mathbb Z_p$ with $\bigcap\limits_p \ker \phi_p=0$?

To start with, if $x\in R$ is an element that satisfies a polynomial equation 
with coefficients in $\mathbb Z$, then $x\in \mathbb Z$ (by Chinese remainder 
theorem). So $R$ must be a transcendental extension of $\mathbb Z$.

Is there a maximal ring resp. a good notion of "maximal element" of such rings? (For example, a ring $R'$ with an injection $:R\rightarrow R'$ making all $\phi_p$-diagrams commutative.)

Comment: No, $\frac{1}{p}$ is not in $\mathbb Z_p$.

Comment: Ah, right, I'm thinking of $\Bbb Q_p$. My bad. (btw, it's `\not\in`, not `\ni`)

Comment: I think your conditions on $R$ just say that it is a subring of $\hat{\mathbb Z} \cong \prod_p \mathbb{Z}_p$.

Comment: @tj_ I think you're right. So should we look at maximal subrings of $\hat{\mathbb Z}$ without zero divisors?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The ring you are looking for is $\widehat{\mathbb{Z}}={\displaystyle\lim_{\leftarrow}\mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z}}$.

This has canonical maps to $\mathbb{Z}_p={\displaystyle\lim_{\leftarrow}\mathbb{Z}/p^k\mathbb{Z}}$ induced by taking $\mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z}\twoheadrightarrow \mathbb{Z}/p^k\mathbb{Z}$ (where $p^k$ is the biggest power of $p$ dividing $N$).

Your condition asks that the product map $\widehat{\mathbb{Z}}\to \prod_p \mathbb{Z}_p$ should be injective; in fact, by the Chinese Remainder Theorem, this map is an isomorphism: $\widehat{\mathbb{Z}}\cong \prod_p \mathbb{Z}_p$. So this is the universal such ring.

---

A broader perspective: passing from $\mathbb{Z}$ to $\widehat{\mathbb{Z}}$ amounts to taking the completion of $\mathbb{Z}$ w.r.t the topology induced by the inclusion $\mathbb{Z}\hookrightarrow \prod_p \mathbb{Z}_p$, so the ring $\widehat{\mathbb{Z}}$ we obtain is the *closure* of $\mathbb{Z}$ inside $\prod_p \mathbb{Z}_p$. The fact that this is *all* of $\prod_p \mathbb{Z}_p$ means that $\mathbb{Z}$ is **dense** in $\prod_p \mathbb{Z}_p$. This density is a weak form of "approximation" (it's the Chinese Remainder Theorem), which is significantly generalized by the classical theorems of [weak and strong approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximation_in_algebraic_groups) (and even [superstrong approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superstrong_approximation)).

Comment: Thank you for this instructive answer! I found now that $F$ is isomorphic $\hat{\mathbb Z}$ which gives a nice representation of $\hat{\mathbb Z}$.

Comment: That $F$ is $\widehat{\mathbf Z}$ can be found in some notes of Lenstra, who either defines $\widehat{\mathbf Z}$ that way or makes it an exercise to show this: http://www.euro-math-soc.eu/system/files/news/Hendrik%20Lenstra_Profinite%20number%20theory.pdf,  http://www.math.leidenuniv.nl/~hwl/papers/fibo.pdf, and http://websites.math.leidenuniv.nl/algebra/Lenstra-Profinite.pdf.